# How to remove main domain header title from after sub domain header title

Tags: headers, wp-title

I have installed WordPress on the main dame in public HTML and have installed all domains in the sub folder. But when we do Google, the title of the main domain comes in the title of all the domains. Why is this happening? If there is any solution, please try to tell.
Please see the screen shot below. This will make you understand the situation soon.[image]

[image]